# MVC Table ID in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Example:
I have an Albums table filled with cd albums and I want to change album number 5 . An album model gets passed to the detail view of AlbumsController.

In the view I can then edit the album fields and submit the changes to album number 5.

If I change the hidden ID value of album number 5 into ID 27 album number 27 will get the values of album number 5

Is there a MVC ASP.Net build in way to prevent changing of keys ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. Can you add some code to your question?

Comment: It is more a generic question. If I in a browser adjust the field that is used to identify the record that needs to be updated I can update the wrong record.

Comment: If it is hidden then why is it getting changed?

Comment: Because there are people who like to use firebug and adjust fields that are hidden.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this problem is to compute the `hash` of Album number and set it in the hidden field. The reason to use `hash` is that it is hard for the user to guess what value is it.

At the same time, hold the computed `hash` on the server `Session`. So next time when user posts data, you can check the posted `hash` with `Session hash`, and if there are one and same, then update the album object. If hashes doesn't match, then throw the error to user saying that data got tampered.

**EDIT**

To check user permissions on a given object, first get `HttpContext.User.Identity` which will give you the information about logged-in user into application. Using this information cross check if the same user got enough permissions on the object (say for example album 123) to perform update/delete operations.

You should be storing somewhere in your database the proper mappings between albums and users for allowed permissions. An index table where AlbumId and UserId should be stored.

Comment: I found a solution that does this. But I would expect this to be a basic feature of ASP.Net.

Comment: ASP.Net MVC only comes up with `AntiForgeryToken` to prevent `CSRF` Attacks. But when it comes to trusting User inputs, then we have to handle it by ourselves through code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you give the user a list of albums to change and permission to change them, then 'change album 5 to X' and 'change album 27 to X' are both valid commands they are going to be able to construct from the information you give them.

I Assume what you mean is,

> how can I prevent a user modifying albums they have no permission to
>   modify by injecting a different id variable.

Once you phrase it like that the answer is obvious. When you receive the change request on the server, check the users permission to change the particular album before you do it!!

Also, using a GUID instead of an int Id, will make you life much easier

Comment: Ok, I get it. English is not my native language, sometimes it is hard to express myself :)